# 1Burzum1 meaning in Black Metal

Tags: black-metal

When I look up releases by Norweigian Black Metal band Burzum on ebay, it's always listed as 1Burzum, 1Burzum1, or Burzum1.  Does anyone know why the 1's are there?  There are no listings I can see with just the band's name, "Burzum".  I'm curious why that is.

Comment: Same reason you can't find a Mel Gibson movie on Netflix. The Cathedral bans and cancels dissidents because they cannot afford to be criticized. Obviously they use other reasons like "he said mean things, hurts people's feelings", etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my observations, almost everyone loathes the individual named Varg Vikernes with a burning passion for killing Øystein Aarseth (whether in cold blood or in self-defense is another story) and for making inflammatory statements many have condemned as racist, sexist, homophobic, transphobic, etc. I cannot name a social media platform he has *not* been banned from (in some cases repeatedly) that he was using in the first place. In short, he is an extremely controversial figure. Based on this fact, my best guess is that people selling Burzum merchandise or releases on eBay or other sites may try to mess with the search engines in the hopes that they are not seen to be associated with or even supportive of Burzum. This is most likely the purpose of the ones, but it is also a fairly common, simple text-decoration.

Hope this helps and rock on!

Comment: I think this is highly plausible and eBay is very touchy about many things (and it's probably for the best). Maybe the exact term Burzum is blacklisted and making it 1Burzum1 is enough to mislead any automatic tools that eBay surely uses.

Comment: I did speak to someone very knowledgeable in ebay *and* Black metal who assured me that "Burzum" is a banned word on ebay listings due to Varg's outspoken racism.